# Sql query with 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have these tables:

1. tblCountry - country_number , country_name
2. tblDivingClub - club_number , country_number(FK)
3. tblDiver - diver_number, diver_name, startWorkingDate, endrtWorkingDate.
4. tblWorks_for -diver_number(FK), club_number(FK)

i need to write a query, without views or temp tables, that will diplay a lits of countries with the fields: country_number , country_name, and the number of diving clubs in that country which have 25 or more working divers at the moment (end working date IS NULL).

thats the code i wrote so far:

```
SELECT country_number, country_name,
(   SELECT count(distinct tblDivingClub.number) 
    FROM tblDivingClub 
    inner join tblCountry on tblDivingClub.country = tblCountry.country_number
     WHERE (
        (  SELECT count(tblWorks_for.diver_number) 
           FROM tblWorks_for 
           INNER JOIN tblDivingClub on  tblWorks_for.club_number = tblDivingClub.number 
           WHERE tblWorks_for.end_working_date IS null
                and tblDivingClub.number =   tblWorks_for.club_number) >25)
) as number_of_clubs
FROM tblCountry 
INNER JOIN tblDivingClub on tblCountry.country_number = tblDivingClub.country 
WHERE tblCountry.country_number = tblDivingClub.country 
GROUP by country_number, country_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT country_number, country_name, COUNT(DISTINCT club_number)
FROM
(
    SELECT tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.club_number, count(*) as tot_cnt
    FROM tblCountry tc
    INNER JOIN tblDivingClub AS tdc   ON tdc.country_number = tc.country_number
    INNER JOIN tblWorks_for  AS tw    ON tw.club_number = tdc.club_number
    INNER JOIN tblDiver      AS td    ON td.diver_number = tw.diver_number
    WHERE endrtWorkingDate IS NULL
    GROUP BY tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.club_number
    HAVING count(*) >= 25
) as der
GROUP BY country_number, country_name;
```

Comment: i'm getting an error over "der": "no column name was specified for column 4 of der". might know what that means?

Comment: edited my answer to be sql server compliant (was testing against MySQL)

Comment: "Column 'tblWorks_for.club_number' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
(frustrated smiley)

Comment: Paste the query you are running, or try the one currently in the answer.  The select is from tblDivingClub not tblWorks_for, so not sure where you are getting that from

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked for you. Please accept this answer. As an aside, let me know if you want an explanation of what's happening in the query

Answer (score 1):

It's a good thing SQL anticipates the need for aggregate conditionals - if you suspected there must be a much easier way, you were right.  I think you want something like:

```
SELECT country_number, country_name, count(distinct tblDivingClub.number) 
FROM tblCountry 
INNER JOIN tblDivingClub on tblCountry.country_number = tblDivingClub.country 
WHERE tblCountry.country_number = tblDivingClub.country 
GROUP by country_number, country_name
HAVING count(case when tblWorks_for.end_working_date IS null then 1 else null end) > 25
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! unfortunately i tried it but the outcome is incorrect :(